# Qt applications drive my mouse crazy?

Tags: mouse, kde

Today I upgraded to Maverick, and tried to watch a movie with smplayer. After a while I stopped the movie and noticed that I could not use my mouse anymore. No left click ,just middle and right clicks worked and I could not grab the focus of any window. This happened with VLC too, but does not happen with mplayer. I can only fix it whit logout/login.
Anyone faced this problem too?

Comment: Maybe it's useful to know if you have this with other applications than mediaplayers too.  And if you only have this when using them full screen or always...

Answer (score 2):

I found the bug which coses my problem
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/636311
Ohh and by the way its not related to Qt
and upgrading xserver-xorg-input-evdev from the xorg-edgers ppa fixed my problem.